# Linking to Static libraries

Tags: d

Coming from a C/C++ background. What is the proper way to link a D static (or dynamic) library to a D .exe file? Can I simply "import" the module from the library and then link to the .lib file at compile time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for static libs, but you also need to pass the library's sources or *.di files to the compiler via -I.

I think D does not have good (or any?) support for dynamic libs at present, though it is high on the todo list.